# Android: Image Pixel Question

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-resolution

I have a simple question here regarding image.

I have this image 300x240pixel on my laptop screen, however when i put it into the android phone, it becomes smaller. why is this so?

I did some research before posting here, apparently this got to do with dpi? Is it possible to to have the same 300x240 size on my laptop screen to be displayed on the android phone without being pixelated?

Thank You

Comment: ya. its all about the screen resolutions of the device. In high resolution screen the images is display in high density.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will need to use the different dpi sections in res/drawable folders.  Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html